# How to dynamically add to double[]?

Tags: android, list, double

How to dynamically add to double[]?
Should I create a List...

```
List<double[]> y = new ArrayList<double[]>();
y.add(new double[15]);    
y.add(new double[20]);
```

and convert List to double[]?

Answer (score 0):

use a `List<Double>` such as `List<Doulble> list = new ArrayList<Double>();`
add whatever the numbers to the list and then convert the list to array:
`Double[] asArray = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but let's see if I can shed some light on things.

An `ArrayList` works like an array that will automatically grow in size as you add items to it. So `ArrayList<Double>` is very similar to a `double[]`, with the exception that you cannot alter the size of the `double[]` after it's been created.

For example, `double[] list = new double[10];` creates an array that holds doubles, but it can never hold more than 10 items. On the other hand, `List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();` can hold 10 items, it can hold 100 items, and it can hold millions of items, all without recreating the list.

Lets look at dynamically expanding an array of doubles:

```
// Create the array
double[] list = new double[2];
list[0] = 1.1;
list[1] = 2.2;
// Copy the array with space for another entry
list = Arrays.copyOf(list, 3);
// Add another entry to the newly expanded array
list[3] = 3.3;
```

Every time you want to hold more values than the array has the capacity for, you will need to create a new array, and copy the values from one to the other (Which is what `Arrays.copyOf(...)` does).

Using an `ArrayList<Double>` simplifies things by handling all of this nonsense internally, so you don't have to worry about maintaining an array of the proper size.

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(1.1);
list.add(2.2);
list.add(3.3);
```

You can keep adding without worrying about what size your `ArrayList` actually is.

With this, you can replace `double[]` with `ArrayList<Double>`. If you need to turn your `ArrayList<Double>` into a `double[]` for whatever reason, that is reasonably simple to do:

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```